# Using if/else syntax for assign statements

Tags: verilog

I have a `wire` to which I assign a complex right-hand-side expression with lots of bitwise operations. This right-hand-side expression is quickly becoming long and hard to maintain.

Is there a way I could replace the bitwise operations by `if/else` or `case` statements to help readability and maintability?

Comment: Can't you just define intermediate wires? Then you can also give your intermediate signals intelligible names, further improving maintainability...

Comment: Also, many people avoid it in C-family programming languages, but to be proficient in Verilog you **must** become familiar with the ternary operator `?:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can, just use the `always @(*)` construct (you need to make it a `reg`). You can handle `inout` ports easily too.

```
reg res;
assign inout_port = dir_out? res: 1'bz;
always @(*) begin
    if (x == 42 && y != z)
        res = 10;
    else
        res = y * 12;
end
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot make it a `reg` because it is an `inout` port.

Comment: I've edited. Note that you shouldn't be using `inout` ports for internal connections anyway.